# difficulty in using Neo4j load csv command

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have a csv file with 38,0000,0000 rows, each line has two names which means two people know each other:

```
name,friend
a,b
a,c
a,d
f,a
e,a
d,g
```

**I need to calculate all people relations.**

firstly, I use cypher:

```
CREATE (n:Patent {name:'a'})
CREATE (n:Patent {name:'b'})
CREATE (n:Patent {name:'c'})
CREATE (n:Patent {name:'d'})
CREATE (n:Patent {name:'e'})
CREATE (n:Patent {name:'f'})
CREATE (n:Patent {name:'g'})



MATCH (a:Patent {name:'a'}), 
      (b:Patent {name:'b'}) 
MERGE (a)-[:CITED]->(b)


MATCH (a:Patent {name:'a'}), 
      (b:Patent {name:'c'}) 
MERGE (a)-[:CITED]->(b)


MATCH (a:Patent {name:'a'}), 
      (b:Patent {name:'d'}) 
MERGE (a)-[:CITED]->(b)


MATCH (a:Patent {name:'f'}), 
      (b:Patent {name:'a'}) 
MERGE (a)-[:CITED]->(b)


MATCH (a:Patent {name:'e'}), 
      (b:Patent {name:'a'}) 
MERGE (a)-[:CITED]->(b)



MATCH (a:Patent {name:'d'}), 
      (b:Patent {name:'g'}) 
MERGE (a)-[:CITED]->(b)
```

then, I got the result:

[image]

but the number of rows is too large, I tried `load csv` batch import command:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///friend_relation.csv" AS line
MATCH (a:Friend {name: line.name}), 
      (b:Friend {name: line.friend}) MERGE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
```

It failed:

[image]

I split the big file into many samll file and use `csv load` to achieve my goal, what is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't return anything it is because the `MATCH` clause doesn't find anything:

Try using

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///friend_relation.csv" AS line
MERGE (a:Friend {name: line.name})
MERGE (b:Friend {name: line.friend}) 
MERGE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
```